# How to bold/underline copy in an antd tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, antd

I have a helper that returns a string for an antd tooltip that needs to have a portion bolded and underlined.

I have tried to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with no luck.

I have also tried to use antd's Typography:

```
`Some normal text ${(<Text strong>and some bold</Text>)}`
```

which results in:

> Some normal text [object Object]

Comment: it will result in object object if u use object in backtick unless u use a different approach
could u give us what u used before with dangerouslySetInnerHTML  and it didn't worked just as fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you can do it simply by passing a `JSX` statement to `title` props (check [this](https://ant.design/components/tooltip#api) out).

For example:

```
<Tooltip title={
  <>
    <strong>bolded part</strong> plain part <u>underlined part</u>
  </>
}>
  <span>Tooltip will show on mouse enter.</span>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

It get stringified, so using antd components won't work. Use plain  and  for text formatting.